# Struggling to make nursery rhyme conditions work

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I've been making Baa Baa Black Sheep in VB and have gotten stuck on the final bit of my program. Im trying to make the program state whether the user has entered the correct information for the people who own the bags, but it doesn't seem to register the final part. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim WoolAnswer As String = ""
        Dim BagNumber As Integer = 0
        Dim FirstBag As String = ""
        Dim SecondBag As String = ""
        Dim ThirdBag As String = ""

        Console.WriteLine("Do you have any wool?")
        WoolAnswer = Console.ReadLine

        If WoolAnswer = "yes" Then
            Console.WriteLine("How many bags do you have?")
            BagNumber = Console.ReadLine

            If BagNumber = 3 Then
                Console.WriteLine("Who is the first bag for?")
                FirstBag = Console.ReadLine()

                Console.WriteLine("Who is the second bag for?")
                SecondBag = Console.ReadLine

                Console.WriteLine("Who is the third bag for?")
                ThirdBag = Console.ReadLine
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("That is not the correct amount of bags.")
            End If

        Else
            Console.WriteLine("You have no wool.")
        End If

        **If (FirstBag = "master" & SecondBag = "dame" & ThirdBag = "little girl") Then
            Console.WriteLine("You really know your nursery rhymes!")
        End If**
        **This is the part that doesn't work**

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: You get points for the strangest question title I've ever seen on SO.

Comment: that is not the way to write an IF statement; try `If (FirstBag = "master" AndAlso SecondBag = "dame" AndAlso ThirdBag = "little girl") Then`  the ampersand is for string concatenation

Comment: *Roses are red, violets are blue, & is for concatenation; AndAlso for you.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `AndAlso` operators to compare your values.

`If FirstBag = "master" AndAlso SecondBag = "dame" AndAlso ThirdBag = "little girl" Then`

You could do it with plain `And` operators, but `AndAlso` supports short-circuiting.

Edit: Short-circuiting is a programming construct which allows you to skip over evaluation of portions of a multi part conditional statement if an earlier portion of the statement renders checking the rest of the statement pointless.

Example: `a == b AndAlso c == d` will not attempt to evaluate `c == d` if `a == b` returns `false`

Comment: describe `short circuiting` for an upvote; the OP obviously doesnt know much about either form

Comment: @Plutonix Welp, ya got me.